# Wrapping words with a titled span with PHP

Tags: php, replace, words, glossary

i'm working on a website that includes a glossary, in which a few words are explained.
Additionaly I want to describe the terms in an article by putting them in spans with a title attribute.

I get all the terms from the database in an array:

```
$terms = array(
    'word1' => 'This is a short description of word1',
    'word2' => 'word2 maybe has something to do with word1'
);
```

The String containing the text could be:

```
$string = 'In this sentence I want to explain both, word1 and word2.';
```

I tried to simply replace the words contained in the string by a simple str_ireplace():

```
foreach($terms as $term => $description)
{
    $string = str_ireplace($term, '<span class="help" title="' . $description . '">' . $term . '</span>', $string);
}
```

What happens now is, that word1 and word2 is replaced correctly. But by iterating a second time over the text to search and replace word2, it finds word1 again - in the title of the already created span.

So the result for word1 would look like this:

```
<span class="help" title="This is a short description of <span class="help" title="This is a short description of word1">word1</span>word1</span>
```

How could I prevent PHP from replacing the same word in the title tag of an existing span? I wouldn't like to use preg_replace() for that, to not parse html to it.

How could I do that?

Lovely Greets from germany
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) for that:

```
$string = 'In this sentence I want to explain both, word1 and word2.';
$terms = array(
    'word1' => '<span title="This is a short description of word1">word1</span>',
    'word2' => '<span title="word2 maybe has something to do with word1">word1</span>',
);
echo strtr($string, $terms);
```

> In this sentence I want to explain both, <span title="This is a short
>   description of word1">word1</span> and <span title="word2 maybe has
>   something to do with word1">word1</span>.

See http://codepad.org/VEBLQcBe for a working example

`strtr` will translate characters or replace substrings

Comment: Oh man, i've been looking for a solution for a week.. :/ THANKS SO MUCH! But strtr is case-sensitive, isn't it? Is there any way or alternative to get it case-insensitive?

Comment: @chris.ribal if you look in the comments section of the `strtr` manual page there are some `stritr` implementations.